# Microsoft Office 365 Addin Angular Form

Tags: javascript, angular.js, form

This is my first time making an Office 365 Addin and wanted advice on my current form structure.

I'm particularly looking for advice on best partices for constructing directives and how to properly separate logic into app controllers. I feel that my single controller below and various redundancies could cause issues in code reuse in the future.

[Repo](https://github.com/jessawong/insightsaddin/tree/ceea5a91f4b0b9f7662561ee09aa5f66aab2ac37)

```
(function () {

  'use strict';



  var app = angular.module('readHome', []);

  var info = { 'te': '', 'pbe': '', 'si': '', 'isv': '', 'website': '', 'date': '', 'time': '', 'reason': '', 'meeting': 'Skype', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'engagement': '', 'crm': '', 'stage': '' };
  var cloudInfo = { 'status': '', 'provider': '', 'consumption': '', 'workloads': '' };

  Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      info.te = Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName;
    });
  };

  app.controller('FormController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.formFields = [
      {
        CrystalGem: "Steven"
      },
      {
        Diamond: "Pink"
      }
    ];

    info["Technology"] = "Intelligent Cloud";
    $scope.technology = [{ 'type': 'Intelligent Cloud', 'url': '../../images/cloud.png', 'alias': 'usdxrisvintelligentcloudteam@service.microsoft.com', 'fadeUrl': '../../images/cloudOverlay.png', 'intel': true }];
    $scope.engagement = ['Briefing', 'Envisioning', 'ADS', 'Hackfest/PoC', 'Other'];;
    $scope.cloudInfor = { 'status': '', 'provider': '', 'consumption': '', 'workloads': '' };
    $scope.cloudStatus = ['New', 'Experimenting', 'Hybrid', 'Running'];
    $scope.cloudProv = ['None', 'Azure', 'AWS', 'Google', 'Other'];
    $scope.consumption = ['<25k', '25k-99k', '100k-499k', '500k+'];
    $scope.workloads = { 'Identity & Access Mgt': false, 'Compute': false, 'Networking': false, 'Storage & DR': false, 'Big Data & SQL': false, 'IoT': false, 'Advanced Analytics': false, 'PaaS Services': false, 'OSS Platforms': false, 'Mobility': false, 'Media Solutions': false };
    $scope.information = info;
    $scope.timeOptions = ['30 min', '60 min', '90 min', '120 min', '2+ hours'];
    $scope.skype = false;
    $scope.intelCloud = true;
    $scope.showArrow = true;
    $scope.showCont = false;
    $scope.ads = false;
    $scope.showSubmit = false;
    $scope.showBack = false;
    $scope.stages = ['0%', '10%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '95%', '100%'];
    $scope.showMain = true;
    $scope.goBack = function () {
      $scope.showCont = false;
      $scope.showMain = true;
      $scope.showArrow = true;
      $scope.showBack = false;
      $scope.showSubmit = false;
    };

    $scope.setWork = function (option) {
      option.value = !option.value;
    };

    $scope.cont = function () {
      $scope.showCont = true;
      $scope.showBack = true;
      $scope.showSubmit = true;
      $scope.showMain = false;
      $scope.showArrow = false;
    };

    $scope.addRequest = function () {
      var cloudDetails = '';
      if ($scope.intelCloud) {
        cloudDetails = "<br/><h4>Industry/Vertical: </h4>" + $scope.cloudInfor.industry + 
        "<br/><h4>Cloud Status: </h4>" + this.cloudInfor.status + 
        "<br/><h4>Cloud Provider: </h4>" + $scope.cloudInfor.provider + 
        "<br/><h4>Annual Consumption: </h4>" + this.cloudInfor.consumption;
        var workloadString = "[";
        for (var key in $scope.workloads) {
          if ($scope.workloads[key]) {
            workloadString += key + ",";
          }
        }
        workloadString = workloadString.substr(0, workloadString.length - 1) + "]";
      }

      Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.setAsync("Intelligent Cloud TE Request");
      Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
        "<h4>PBE: </h4>" + $scope.information.pbe +
        "<h4>SI: </h4>" + $scope.information.si +
        "<h4>ISV: </h4>" + $scope.information.isv +
        "<h4>Product's Website: </h4>" + $scope.information.website +
        "<br/><h4>CRM Link: </h4>" + $scope.information.crm +
        "<br/><h4>Stage:</h4>" + $scope.information.stage +
        "<br/><h4>Engagement Requested: </h4>" + $scope.information.engagement +
        "<br/><h4>Requested Date for Engagement:</h4>" + $scope.information.date +
        "<br/><h4>Reason:</h4>" + $scope.information.reason +
        "<br/><h4>Duration of meeting:</h4>" + $scope.information.time +
        "<br/><h4>Location:</h4>" + $scope.information.location +
        "<br/><h4>Meeting:</h4>" + $scope.information.meeting + cloudDetails +
        "<br/><h4>Workloads:</h4>" + workloadString, { coercionType: "html" }
      );

      var payload = {
        "TE": info.te,
        "PBE": $scope.information.pbe,
        "SI": $scope.information.si,
        "ISV": $scope.information.isv,
        "Website": $scope.information.website,
        "Crm": $scope.information.crm,
        "Stage": $scope.information.stage,
        "EngagementType": $scope.information.engagement,
        "Date": $scope.information.date,
        "Reason": $scope.information.reason,
        "City": $scope.information.city,
        "State": $scope.information.state,
        "Meeting": $scope.information.meeting,
        "Industry": $scope.cloudInfor.industry,
        "cloudStatus": $scope.cloudInfor.status,
        "cloudProvider": $scope.cloudInfor.provider,
        "consumption": $scope.cloudInfor.consumption,
        "workLoads": workloadString
      };

      var namespace = "insightsaddin-eh";
      var hubname = "insights-eh";
      var key_name = "send";

      var ehClient = new EventHubClient(
        {
          'name': hubname,
          'namespace': namespace,
          'sasKey': "HsoQY4aVbX2cOEhg5hqwfzQDSLLIKyvvIrNt/u2jU+k=",
          'sasKeyName': "send",
          'timeOut': 100,
        });

      var msg = new EventData(payload);

      ehClient.sendMessage(msg, function (messagingResult) {
        if (messagingResult.result == "Success") {
          showStatus("#submission");
        } else {
          showStatus("#error");
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });

      $scope.showBack = false;
      $scope.workloads = workLoads;
      $scope.skype = false;
    };
    $scope.canSkype = function () {
      $scope.skype = !$scope.skype;
    };

  });

  function showStatus(domId) {
    $("#form").hide();
    $(domId).show();
  }

  function hideStatus() {
    $("#submission").hide();
  }

  function showForm() {
    $("#form").show();
  }

})();
```